# setting up a sub domain on windows hosting

Tags: windows, hosting, subdomain

I'm trying to set up a sub domain for development on a windows server and am having problems setting the correct details in the httpd.ini file and hoped someone could help.

I have set up the subdomain

`http://dev.website.com`

The files that I want to use for this subdomain are on the server in a folder called development

`http://www.website.com/development`

in the directory structure they are in

`/htdocs/development`

What do I need to add the the httpd.ini file to point the `http://dev.website.com` to the files located in the `/htdocs/development` folder on the server?

Comment: What webserver are you using? Is httpd.ini what Apache-on-Windows calls httpd.conf?

Comment: @rup I believe it's ISAPI Rewrite http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/ and I think they support a very similar rewrite syntax to Apache

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating a subdomain on windows server](http://serverfault.com/questions/152171/creating-a-subdomain-on-windows-server)

Answer (score 1):

Aren't vhosts supposed to be implemented as vhosts instead of rewrites?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/examples.html

dev.website.com
/htdocs/development

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /htdocs
ServerName www.website.com
ServerAlias website.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /htdocs/development
ServerName dev.website.com
ServerAlias www.dev.website.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its ISAPI rewrite I think.

@Jeff - thanks for the link i'll take a look and try to work it out.

Ok so I tried adding the following to the httpd.ini file and its not working. Is this what i need to be doing?

**#Fix missing trailing slash char on folders**
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+[^.?/])$ $1/ [R]

**#Fix duplicate content problem**

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} .*myserver.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/subdomain/([^/?]+)(.+) http://$1.myserver.com$2 [NC,R=301]

**#Map requests to the folders**

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?!www.)([^.]+).myserver.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/%1$1